# What makes an unfrozen room not appear in the active tab list?

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

I noticed that [main chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/19597/project-management) of Project Management Stack Exchange is not shown in the active list. It is not shown even I select "[people](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19597/project-management)" or "[event](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=event&host=chat.pm.stackexchange.com)" tab. Not even when I select to see frozen/deleted rooms. It's only visible when I select "mine" tab. This is not created as a discussion room between two users but by feeds as a replacement of old chat room with the same name.

What makes an unfrozen chat room not appear in the active list? Does having a frozen with the same name stop the newly created room not appear in the active list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like it had an invalid parent hostname set somehow. It was `chat.pm.stackexchange.com` instead of `pm.stackexchange.com`. I fixed that up, so the room should show up as normal now.